# Wordpress Jigoshop cart contents changed

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, plugins, jigoshop

looking for information on how jigoshop for Wordpress stores the current cart contents as a cookie? I'm looking for a way to detect if the cart contents have changed Any suggestions?
Sessions, cookies, db tables - I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone's interested, it's all stored in session data.